# superclass of breeze distributions

Tags: scala, breeze, scala-breeze

I am trying to use Breeze distributions as an argument to a function. A trivial example would be:

```
def foo(d: D, x: Double) = d.logPdf(x)
```

I would like this to work for examples

```
foo(Gassian(0,1),0.5)
foo(Laplace(0,1),0.5)
```

The problem is I do not know what "D" should be in the function signiature, or the name of the more general concept which I am encountering here.

Comment: If both `Gaussian` and `Laplace` descend from the same class `Distribution`: `def foo[D <: Distribution](d: D, x: Double) = ...`

Comment: How do I find the class they are derived from

Comment: Looking at the source code? `case class Gaussian(...) extends ContinuousDistr[Double] ...`. So `def foo[D <: ContinuousDistr[Double]](...)`.